# Suggest a free jquery plugin that replaces default browser scrollbar?

Tags: jquery, scrollbar

I am finding a customizable jquery plugin that can replace replace the default browser scroll. Most of the plugins that i find on internet only replaces scroll in div tag. I found rollbar but it is paid. Please suggest a free plugin.

Answer (score 0):

you can target webkit browsers such as Chrome with just CSS.

http://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/

or for IE use scrollbar

```
 body {
            scrollbar-3dlight-color:#000;
            scrollbar-arrow-color:#000;
            scrollbar-track-color:#000 ;
            scrollbar-darkshadow-color:#000;
            scrollbar-face-color:#000;
            scrollbar-highlight-color:#000;
            scrollbar-shadow-color:#000;
            }
```

however, as far as I know there still isn't any vendor prefix for Firefox, it's been an outstanding bug for 13 years! https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=77790